# Pseudo-Euclidean orbifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology, orbifolds

Are there any papers (reviews) devoted mainly to pseudo-Euclidean orbifolds in mathematics and physics (e.g. string theory)? A more specific question is related to orbifolds of type $\mathbb R^{1,4m-3}/Z_2$, where $\mathbb R^{1,4m-3}$ is pseudo-Euclidean flat space of dimension $4m-2$, $m = 1,2, \dots$, with the standard action of the discrete group $Z_2: x \to -x$.